# What function can I use to conditionally format text depending on cursor position or active cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I have a 'Freeze' on Column A.

I want the text in Column A, Row X to Conditionally Format as **BOLD RED**, while my cursor is on any cell for Row X.

Is there a way to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

Bad news. There isn't.

Google Sheets formulas doesn't "see" the cursor, actually can't see either a selection (cell, range, row, column, area). Google Apps Script can't see either the cursor of Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to manage that in conditional formatting with regular formulas, nor with the script.

Best you can have is to highlight the cursor with some software or some extension like **[this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-cursor-for-chrome/ogdlpmhglpejoiomcodnpjnfgcpmgale?hl=en)** and run this extension only when you are in Google Sheets.

```
chrome://extensions/
```

[image]